# disable caching of page J2ee Taglib

Tags: jakarta-ee, taglib, scriptlet

I wanna know if there is a way to write this scriptlet in a taglib

```
response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"); // HTTP 1.1.
response.setHeader("Pragma", "no-cache"); // HTTP 1.0.
response.setDateHeader("Expires", 0); // Proxies.
```

Because i want to separate java code from JSP.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use the `ojsp:cacheXMLObj` or `ojsp:cache` tag to enable caching and specify cache settings. 
Use `ojsp:useCacheObj` to cache any Java serializable object. 
Use the `ojsp:invalidateCache` tag to invalidate a cache block. 
Alternatively, you can arrange invalidation through the invalidateCache attribute of the `ojsp:cacheXMLObj` or `ojsp:cache` tag.

You can have more information here : https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B14099_19/web.1012/b14016/jwcache.htm